# Self map extending to its resolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety and $f$ be a finite self map of $X$, which takes smooth locus to smooth locus. Let $Y$ be a projective resolution of $X$.

Question; Does the map $f$ induce a self map $g$ of $Y$ which commutes with the map $f$ and the resolution maps ?

Comment: If you really mean for  $X$ to be an arbitrary resolution of $Y$, then no:  Let $f:Y\to Y$ be an automorphism, and $X\to Y$ be blow up where the centre is not invariant under $f$.

Comment: The resolution of Hironaka respects smooth morphisms, e.g., etale morphisms.  This also holds for some of the later resolution algorithms.

Comment: @Donu Arapura I..I have some more condition on $X$ and on the map. We can assume that $X$  has only terminal singularity and has Piard rank 1 and the map takes singular locus to singular locus. Now the question  is ; does there exist a projective resolution with the above property?

Comment: @Jason Starr ... I did not understand your comments. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: @Donu Arapura...sorry canonical singularity

Comment: Hironaka associates to every finit type, separated, reduced  scheme $X$ over a characteristic $0$ field $k$ a projective $k$-morphism $\nu_X: \widetilde{X}\to X$ that is a strong resolution of singularities and such that for every smooth $k$-morphism $f:Z\to X$, there is a unique $k$-morphism $\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{Z}\to \widetilde{X}$ such that that $\nu_X\circ \widetilde{f}$ equals $f\circ \nu_Z$.

Comment: Are finite morphisms of normal projective varieties smooth?

Comment: Not all finite morphisms are smooth.  Resolution is not compatible with arbitrary finite morphisms.  If a smooth point of the domain maps to a singular point of the target, there is no compatible map of resolutions.  For a smooth morphism, every smooth point maps to a smooth point, and then Hironaka gives a compatible map of resolutions.

Comment: Generally finite morphism is not unramified...but in our situation smooth locus maps to smooth locus...is the result holds for such situation ?

Comment: In your original post, there is no hypothesis that the smooth locus maps to the smooth locus.  Are you adding new hypotheses?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add that hypothesis. Now I have added it.